# How do I change the ImageIcon of a JLable stored within an array?

Tags: java, imageicon

I have 9 JLables which I created and set a default image.

Now I need to change a specific JLable image within the array. How can I do this?

Thanks!

```
 for (int i = 0; i < imgBoxArray.length; i++)
    {
        imgBoxArray[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Users/cameronmurray/Dropbox/JAVA 2/SmartHome/src/smarthome/clock.jpg"));
        imgBoxArray[i].setOpaque(true);
        imagePanel.add(imgBoxArray[i]);
    }    

    imgBoxArray[i].ImageIcon("/Users/cameronmurray/Dropbox/JAVA 2/SmartHome/src/smarthome/clock.jpg")); //ERROR
```

Comment: `imgBoxArray[foo].setImageIcon(bar);` What confuses you in particular?

Comment: You can't use `i` outside of the loop since it is out of scope and only exists inside of the loop. This has nothing to do with Swing and all to do with basic Java.

Answer (score 0):

First off modern idiomatic Java doesn't use raw arrays, it uses type safe `List<JLabel>` implementations.

But to answer you specific question:

```
imgBoxArray[3].setIcon();
```

will let you modify what is in the 4th slot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the JLabel at `ith` index(say index `1`) of array then you can simply use:

```
imgBoxArray[1].setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/cameronmurray/Dropbox/JAVA 2/SmartHome/src/smarthome/clock.jpg")) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

retrieve the 'good' JLabel index and then :

```
imgBoxArray[index].setIcon(...)
```